# Keras - ValueError when compiling model

Tags: keras

I am new to Keras. I want to reproduce the example of imdb in Keras (Backend: Tensorflow) and I get an error when trying to compile the model.

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
             loss='binary_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])

ValueError: Only call `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named 
arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)
```

Any advice?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What Keras and TF versions are you using?

Comment: That sounds pretty weird.... Try changing `rmsprop` to `adam`, just to check...

Comment: This is a bug in TensorFlow and not your code. I recommend downgrade to an older version.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on to run the above code in Spyder. The code ran fine for me, it does not through any ValueError.

I think in your case the problem may be in the backend that is being used by Keras. I am using Tensorflow backend.

TO change the backend either edit your keras.json file in ~/.keras folder.
Here is an example of keras.json file

{
    "epsilon": 1e-07, 
    "floatx": "float32", 
    "image_data_format": "channels_last", 
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}